# (Power Automate, Microsoft Forms connector) Finding Form using FormID?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, power-automate

I have inherited a bunch of flows from a former co-worker. One of these flows are using the: "When a response is submitted" Microsoft Forms connector as a trigger.

The connection is made using my former co-workers 'personal' work account and I need to switch it to mine (a service acc).

Now, my co-worker shared access to relevant SharePoint sites before leaving but must have forgotten to share access to this specific Form. I am unable to locate the form in our SharePoint setup and have even had our administrator try and help me look but no luck so far.

Looking at the connector the only thing I have to go from is a "Form ID", which I haven't been able to find much info about except for how to extract it to use in flows.

The form ID looks like this:
Xz9pUAX8ika_qIDyEUYU05TNwO5_-kpFmx7-D65GU8lUNFYzWkg1MUY2VEo3VTExSEdSVDBZT*******

I do not know how or if this ID is sensitive at all so I gave blanked out the last few digits to be safe. If seeing the full ID makes a difference and is not a security hazard I wouldn't mind sharing it.

Does anyone know a trick for locating a Microsoft Forms using a FormsID?

Comment: Does this help ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noj4cL6S3wc

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you´re in luck. The ID can be used when properly used in the HTML. For the following examples, I used the ID that you provided.
The standard link that you use for sending and collecting respones should look like this: https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=Xz9pUAX8ika_qIDyEUYU05TNwO5_-kpFmx7-D65GU8lUNFYzWkg1MUY2VEo3VTExSEdSVDBZT*******

The "Share to collaborate" link should look like this: https://forms.office.com/Pages/DesignPageV2.aspx?subpage=design&FormId=Xz9pUAX8ika_qIDyEUYU05TNwO5_-kpFmx7-D65GU8lUNFYzWkg1MUY2VEo3VTExSEdSVDBZT*******

The last link only works depending on the settings.
[Share to collaborate settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqZ4g.png)

If it doesn´t hopefully the first link can hopefully help you in copying the content.